Pogit Model: Correlated or Orthogonal Covariates?
I’m working with the following Pogit model:
Y ~ Pois(lambdap)
log(lambda) = alpa_0 + alpha_1x_1 + alpha_2x_2
logit(p) = gamma_0+gamma_1t_1 + gamma_2*t_2
I’m conducting a simulation study with two scenarios:

In the first scenario, the covariates of the Poisson mean model are uncorrelated with those of the logit model.
In the second scenario, however, (X_1) is highly correlated with (T_1), and (X_2) is highly correlated with (T_2).

I would expect better performance in the first scenario, but this doesn’t seem to be the case. When considering the coverage of the credible intervals (I’m working in a Bayesian framework), some parameters perform better in the first scenario, while others perform better in the second.
Does anyone have theoretical insights or references in the literature that might explain why my initial assumptions are not holding true?
Thank you!
Simulation code:
library(MASS)
library(rje)
library(R2jags)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(Matrix)
library(ggplot2)
library(gtools)

set.seed(123)

#Data shared from all scenarios ----

#Define the covariates means (zero mean for all covariates)
mean_vector <- rep(0, 4)

#n of simulations
n = 250

#coefficients
#a0 = 0
a1 = 0.5
a2 = 0.3
b0_sim = 0.5
b1 = 0.8
b2 = 0.6

coefficient = c(a1, a2, b0_sim, b1, b2)

coeff_names <-  c("a1", "a2",
                  "b0", "b1", "b2")

#Sample size

N <- 100 

#Scenario 0 -----

##Data Scenario 0 --- all covariates are ortogonal
sim_scenario0 = list()
sim_scenario0$N=N # Number of observations.

corr_matrix_scenario0 <- matrix(c(3,0,0,0,
                                  0,3,0,0,
                                  0,0,3,0,
                                  0,0,0,3),
                                ncol = 4,
                                nrow = 4)

simulation_scenario0 <- function(k){
  
  CI_95 <- vector("list", length(coefficient))
  CI_95_i <- vector("list", length(coefficient))
  
  for(i in 1:k){
    print(paste("Simulation n.",i))
    
    #Generate multivariate normal data with the defined covariance structure
    
    sim_scenario0$data <- mvrnorm(n = sim_scenario0$N, 
                                  mu = mean_vector, 
                                  Sigma = corr_matrix_scenario0,
                                  empirical = T)
    
    round(cor(sim_scenario0$data), digits = 5)
    
    #Convert the data to a data frame and check
    colnames(sim_scenario0$data) <- c(paste0("X", 1:2),
                                      paste0("Z", 1:2))
    
    #Standardize logit covariates as in the application
    sim_scenario0$data[,"X1"] <- scale(sim_scenario0$data[,"X1"])
    sim_scenario0$data[,"X2"] <- scale(sim_scenario0$data[,"X2"])
    sim_scenario0$data[,"Z1"] <- scale(sim_scenario0$data[,"Z1"])
    sim_scenario0$data[,"Z2"] <- scale(sim_scenario0$data[,"Z2"])
    
    sim_scenario0$lambda=exp(a1*sim_scenario0$data[,"X1"]+
                               a2*sim_scenario0$data[,"X2"]) # Poisson means.
    
    sim_scenario0$y=rpois(sim_scenario0$N,
                          sim_scenario0$lambda) # True counts.
    
    sim_scenario0$pi=inv.logit(b0_sim+b1*sim_scenario0$data[,"Z1"]+
                             b2*sim_scenario0$data[,"Z2"]) # Reporting probabilities.
    
    sim_scenario0$z=rbinom(sim_scenario0$N,
                           sim_scenario0$y,sim_scenario0$pi) # Observed counts.
    
    data_scenario0 = data.frame(z = sim_scenario0$z,
                                x1 = sim_scenario0$data[,"X1"],
                                x2 = sim_scenario0$data[,"X2"],
                                v1 = sim_scenario0$data[,"Z1"],
                                v2 = sim_scenario0$data[,"Z2"])
    
    z <- data_scenario0$z
    x1 <- data_scenario0$x1
    x2 <- data_scenario0$x2
    v1 <- data_scenario0$v1
    v2 <- data_scenario0$v2
    sim.dat.jags <- list("z", "x1", "x2", 
                         "v1", "v2", 
                         "N", "b0_sim")
    
    bayes.mod.params <- c("a1", "a2",
                          "b0", "b1", "b2")
    
    bayes.mod.inits <- function(){
      list("a1" = 0, 
           "a2" = 0, 
           "b0" = b0_sim,
           "b1" = 0,
           "b2" = 0)
    }
    
    bayes.mod.fit <- jags(data = sim.dat.jags, 
                      inits = bayes.mod.inits,
                      parameters.to.save = bayes.mod.params, 
                      n.chains = 3, n.iter = 5000,
                      n.burnin = 1000,
                      model.file = "jags_model.txt")

#bayes.mod.fit.upd <- update(bayes.mod.fit, n.iter=10000)

#print(bayes.mod.fit)

if(0){
  plot(bayes.mod.fit)
  traceplot(bayes.mod.fit)
  
  pdf("bayes_trace.pdf")
  
  traceplot(bayes.mod.fit)
  
  dev.off()
  
  bayes.mod.fit.mcmc <- as.mcmc(bayes.mod.fit)
  summary(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc)
  
  library(mcmcplots)
  
  denplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc)
  
  traplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc, parms = c("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1"))
  
  caterplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc, parms = c("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1"))
}

for (l in 1:length(coefficient)){
  CI_95_i[[l]] <- data.frame(low = round(bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,3][l], digits = 3),
                             upp = round(bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,7][l], digits = 3),
                             true_param = coefficient[l],
                             est_param = bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,1][l],
                             r_hat = bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,8][l])
  
  CI_95[[l]] <- rbind(CI_95[[l]],
                      CI_95_i[[l]]) 
}
  }
  
  return(CI_95)
}

results_0 <- simulation_scenario0(n)

#Scenario 1 ----

sim_scenario1 = list()
sim_scenario1$N=N # Number of observations.

corr_matrix_scenario1 <- matrix(c(3,0,1,0,
                                  0,3,0,0,
                                  1,0,3,0,
                                  0,0,0,3),
                                ncol = 4,
                                nrow = 4)

corr_matrix_scenario1 <- as.matrix(nearPD(corr_matrix_scenario1)$mat)


simulation_scenario1 <- function(k){
  
  CI_95 <- vector("list", length(coefficient))
  CI_95_i <- vector("list", length(coefficient))
  
  for(i in 1:k){
    
    print(paste("Simulation n.",i))
    
    #Generate multivariate normal data with the defined covariance structure
    
    sim_scenario1$data <- mvrnorm(n = sim_scenario1$N, 
                                  mu = mean_vector, 
                                  Sigma = corr_matrix_scenario1,
                                  empirical = T)
    
    round(cor(sim_scenario1$data), digits = 5)
    
    #Convert the data to a data frame and check
    colnames(sim_scenario1$data) <- c(paste0("X", 1:2),
                                      paste0("Z", 1:2))
    
    #Standardize logit covariates as in the application
    sim_scenario1$data[,"X1"] <- scale(sim_scenario1$data[,"X1"])
    sim_scenario1$data[,"X2"] <- scale(sim_scenario1$data[,"X2"])
    sim_scenario1$data[,"Z1"] <- scale(sim_scenario1$data[,"Z1"])
    sim_scenario1$data[,"Z2"] <- scale(sim_scenario1$data[,"Z2"])
    
    
    sim_scenario1$lambda=exp(a1*sim_scenario1$data[,"X1"]+
                               a2*sim_scenario1$data[,"X2"]) # Poisson means.
    
    sim_scenario1$y=rpois(sim_scenario1$N,
                          sim_scenario1$lambda) # True counts.
    
    sim_scenario1$pi=inv.logit(b0_sim+b1*sim_scenario1$data[,"Z1"]+
                                 b2*sim_scenario1$data[,"Z2"]) # Reporting probabilities.
    
    sim_scenario1$z=rbinom(sim_scenario1$N,
                           sim_scenario1$y,sim_scenario1$pi) # Observed counts.
    
    data_scenario1 = data.frame(z = sim_scenario1$z,
                                x1 = sim_scenario1$data[,"X1"],
                                x2 = sim_scenario1$data[,"X2"],
                                v1 = sim_scenario1$data[,"Z1"],
                                v2 = sim_scenario1$data[,"Z2"])
    
    z <- data_scenario1$z
    x1 <- data_scenario1$x1
    x2 <- data_scenario1$x2
    v1 <- data_scenario1$v1
    v2 <- data_scenario1$v2
    
    sim.dat.jags <- list("z", "x1", "x2", 
                         "v1", "v2", 
                         "N", "b0_sim")
    
    bayes.mod.params <- c("a1", "a2",
                          "b0", "b1", "b2")
    
    bayes.mod.inits <- function(){
      list("a1" = 0, 
           "a2" = 0, 
           "b0" = b0_sim,
           "b1" = 0,
           "b2" = 0)
    }
    
    bayes.mod.fit <- jags(data = sim.dat.jags, 
                          inits = bayes.mod.inits,
                          parameters.to.save = bayes.mod.params, 
                          n.chains = 3, n.iter = 5000,
                          n.burnin = 1000,
                          model.file = "jags_model.txt")
    
    #bayes.mod.fit.upd <- update(bayes.mod.fit, n.iter=10000)
    
    #print(bayes.mod.fit)
    
    if(0){
      plot(bayes.mod.fit)
      traceplot(bayes.mod.fit)
      
      pdf("bayes_trace.pdf")
      
      traceplot(bayes.mod.fit)
      
      dev.off()
      
      bayes.mod.fit.mcmc <- as.mcmc(bayes.mod.fit)
      summary(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc)
      
      library(mcmcplots)
      
      denplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc)
      
      traplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc, parms = c("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1"))
      
      caterplot(bayes.mod.fit.mcmc, parms = c("a0", "a1", "b0", "b1"))
    }
    
    for (l in 1:length(coefficient)){
      CI_95_i[[l]] <- data.frame(low = round(bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,3][l], digits = 3),
                                 upp = round(bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,7][l], digits = 3),
                                 true_param = coefficient[l],
                                 est_param = bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,1][l],
                                 r_hat = bayes.mod.fit$BUGSoutput$summary[,8][l])
      
      CI_95[[l]] <- rbind(CI_95[[l]],
                          CI_95_i[[l]]) 
    }
  }
  
  return(CI_95)
}

results_1 <- simulation_scenario1(n)

PS: I'm also attaching my JAGS model:

model {
for (j in 1:N) {
z\[j\] \~ dpois(lambda_obs\[j\])

    lambda_obs[j] <- lambda[j] * pi[j] 
    logit(pi[j]) <- b0 + b1 * v1[j] + b2*v2[j]
    log(lambda[j]) <- a0 + a1 * x1[j] + a2 * x2[j]

}

#Priors
a0 \~ dnorm(0, 1)
a1 \~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
a2 \~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
b0 \~ dnorm(b0_sim, 100)  
b1 \~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
b2 \~ dnorm(0, 0.1)
}

